# Nesting reducers in redux

Tags: redux

Say, I have a store like that:

```
{
  modules: {
    myModule: {
      aFlag: true,
      anotherFlag: false,
      nestedItem: {...}
    },
    ...
  },
  entities: {...},
  ...
}
```

and `modules` reducer is `combineReducers({myModule: myModuleReducer})`
Inside `myModuleReducer` I wanna delegate handling of the `nestedItem` to another reducer, so `myModuleReducer` would handle actions for `aFlag` and `anotherFlag`, while `nestedItem` would be handled by `nestedReducer`.

How can I do that?
It's pretty easy with `combineReducers` if I create a nested namespace for those flags, i.e. if I have

```
myModule: {flags: {aFlag: true, anotherFlag: false}, nestedItem: {...}}
```

I can just do `myModuleReducer = combineReducers({flags: flagReducer, nestedItem: nestedReducer})`
But what if I don't want to create a namespace for those flags and want `myModuleReducer` to handle those, while I want `nestedReducer` to handle `nestedItem`?

I've come up with a "pattern" like this, using `reduce-reducers` package:

```
const nestedReducers = combineReducers({
  // defaults for slices of state not handled by nested reducers
  aFlag: (state = initialState.aFlag) => state,
  anotherFlag: (state = initialState.anotherFlag) => state,
  // nested reducers for particular slices of state
  nestedItems: nestedReducer
});
```

and then

```
const finalReducer = reduceReducers(nestedReducers, myModuleReducer);
```

This ways it seems to make the `nestedReducer` handle `nestedItems` slice and `myModuleReducer` handles top-level parts of state (i.e. `aFlag` and `anotherFlag` fields).

But I don't like that I need to pass those default functions for everything which is not handled by the nested reducer. Can it be avoided? (Ofcourse I can abstract this away to some kind of `nestReducers` helper, but still). In general, what are problems with my approach?

Comment: Big fan of your work, on one hand I'm sorry to know you are giving up poetry to pursue a career in engineering, but hey, if it makes you happy I'm 100% behind you!

Comment: @TobiaTesan that's nice to hear. but maybe there's also some feedback on the topic of the post?..

Answer (score 1):

You could always just do that manually in your `myModuleReducer` function, like this:

```
function myModuleReducer(state = someInitialState, action) {

    // Call nestedReducer here
    const reducedNestedItem = nestedReducer(state, action)

    switch (action.type) {
    case 'MY_ACTION_TYPE':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            aFlag: // aFlag logic
            anotherFlag: // anotherFlag logic
            nestedItem: reducedNestedItem
        })
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

You just need to make sure if you do it like that that you follow Redux's purity philosophy.

Comment: thanks! What I was trying to achieve is to totally ignore the actions, corresponding to `nestedReducer` in `myModuleReducer`. Is that possible? What do you think about approach I've added just now, when editing my post?